# Can I render isolated objects but keeping all the impact of other objects and their materials?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, objects, render-layers

So I chose all the objects I don`t want to be rendered and changed their visibility, and then rendered the object I want, but it looks different while being isolated. Can I render it like if there are all other objects in a scene providing different types of reflections and so? Cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *Indirect Only* restriction toggle option. It's only available for a whole collection. If you enable it, it will hide all the collection's objects but they will still affect the rendered ones.

[image]

Or select an object and disable its camera visibility in the *Properties* panel > *Object > Visibility*:

[image]

Comment: thanks, gonna try it soon!